# Characterization of regulated functions using step functions

Tags: analysis, step-function

Definition: Let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $B$ be a Banach space. Function $f:[a,b]\to B$ is regulated if there exist $f^+(t_0)=\lim_{t \to t_0^+}{f(t)}$ and $f^-(t_0)=\lim_{t \to t_0^-}{f(t)}$, for every $t_0\in [a,b]$.

Characterization: Function $f:[a,b]\to B$ is regulated if and only if there exist a sequence of step functions (piecewise constant functions) $s_n:[a,b]\to B$ that converges to $f$ uniformly.

I tried proving that if $f$ is regulated, then sequence $(s_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ exists by defining $(s_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in the following way:

$s_1$ is constant on $[a,b]$ and $s_1(t)=\frac{f^+(a)+f^-(b)}{2}$ and similarly:

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $t_0,\dots ,t_n \in [a,b]$, $t_k=a+k\frac{b-a}{n}, k\in \{1, \dots ,n\}$. For all $k\in \{1, \dots ,n-1\}$ $s_n$ is constant on $[t_k,t_{k+1}]$ and $s_n(t)=\frac{f^+(t_{k-1})+f^-(t_k)}{2}, t\in [t_k,t_{k+1}]$.

And I don't know what to do now. I'm not sure this idea is good and I don't know how to prove that this converges uniformly to $f$.

As for the proof of the other implication, I'm not sure I know how to do that either. I guess we could say that if there exists $(s_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges uniformly to $f$, then $(\forall t\in [a,b]) \lim_{n\to\infty} {s_n(t)}=f(t)$. 
So we have:
$$f^+(t_0)=\lim_{t\to t_0^+}{\lim_{n\to\infty}{s_n(t)}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\lim_{t\to t_0^+}{s_n(t)}}$$ (limits can switch places because $(s_n)$ converges uniformly?)

$\lim_{t\to t_0^+}{s_n(t)}$ should exist because $s_n$ is a step function, but how to prove that the double limit exists?

Comment: Start with the second implication and work with $\varepsilon$. That's a lot easier than to fiddle around with double limits.

Comment: @amsmath When you say "work with $\varepsilon$" do you mean work with $ \varepsilon$ definition of limit?

Comment: Yes, and that of (Cauchy) sequences.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on the definition of step functions you are using. Do you require them to be constant on intervals, or do you allow (as in measure theory) more general sets? Can the step functions take on a countably infinite number of values, or only a finite number?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function intervals are required, finite number of intervals